# App name not being displayed

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

My Android app is not displaying the application name "app_name",I have multiple activities but when I restart the app, the first page of the app doesn't show the app name but in other activities it shows the app name. i don't know what is wrong anyone can help me.

This is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".HomescreenActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="QuizDetailsActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="QuestionListActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="QuizActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ResultsActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Comment: _"the first page of the app doesn't show the app name"_ where should the app name displayed ? In ActionBar or what ?

Comment: You don't need to set it umpteen times. Just set it once as a property of `Application`.

Comment: I thought the problem was raised by this line android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" in HomescreenActivity.I assumed that you showing appname in action bar.

Comment: your awesome @vishwa thank you. I have changed that to android:theme="@style/AppTheme"> it works now.